# Strange problem with newdocset(Document set) with SPContext.Current.Web while using HttpModule

Tags: document-set, http-module

newdocset doesnot seems to work with SPContext.Current.Web
I have a HttpModule below is a sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Web;

namespace mynamespace
{
    class DemoHttpModule : System.Web.IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
            application.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(this.Application_AcquireRequestState);
            application.ReleaseRequestState += new EventHandler(this.Application_ReleaseRequestState);
            //To Handel page.PreRender
            application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(this.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
        }
        private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication curApp = sender as HttpApplication;
            //SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        }
        private void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication curApp = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (curApp.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("advsetng.aspx"))
            {
                return;
            }

            using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(Convert.ToString(curApp.Request.Url)))
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {

                }
            }
        }
        private void Application_ReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication curApp = sender as HttpApplication;
            SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        }
        private void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication curApp = sender as HttpApplication;
            SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        }
    }
}
```

in Application_AcquireRequestState if i am using

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.ID)
            {
```

Then although it is not generating any exception but shows an error message while creating a newdocset stating "This action cannot be completed"

if i am using

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(Convert.ToString(curApp.Request.Url)))
                {
```

then it is working fine, but the problem with curApp.Request is it will always return the root level web object 
So are there any alternatives to SPContext.Current.Web.ID

in this link the answer suggested by spunkyvt tells something about a similar problem but i cant use the solution suggested by him
[simillar problem link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepoint2010programming/thread/ea0b1380-480f-4b2e-afde-77ed06995bb0)

Any suggestions

Thanks
Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes the issue with the following code

```
    if (Convert.ToString(curApp.Request.Url).ToLower().Contains("newdocset.aspx"))
                    {
                        using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(curApp.Context.Request.Url.ToString()))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                            {
// doing my stuff here
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: ThisSPContext problem with new docset happens only in AcquireState and obviously in BeginRequest

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to create and SPSite with the ID of an SPWeb. That's is never going to work. Try the following instead.

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
{

}
```

Out of curiosity, why are you using an HttpModule? Can't you do it with an invisible custom control injected in the masterpage using the AdditionalPageHead DelegateControl? That way you simplify things a lot more and you should have access to all the context you need from within your control.

I only write custom HttpModules if I can't think of any other solution that works.

Comment: lots of things are going on through this httpmodule i have just giiven a sample code. otherwise it will mess up the whole things
let me see if this works

Comment: Nope i am getting the same error "The action cannot be completed"

Comment: Attach debugger and confirm SPContext.Current.Site.ID contains a Guid.

Comment: ya it does as i mentioned code is generating no exception and returns everything as expected but at the end this error comes
commenting the SPContext line everythings work as desired, but i need the current web object

Comment: Why are you instantiating a new SPWeb if you already have one in the Context? why not use SPContext.Current.Web itself?

Comment: I tried that also i dont know but it seems newdocset is having some problem with SPContext.Current if it encounter this while processing it generates an error

Comment: But you mentioned you are able to read the current Web ID from it so it looks like it was loaded ok

Comment: Thanks jaap now i am able to fix the issue i have added that as an answer